# Populating and array in a matrix style

Tags: arrays, matrix

I want to populate an array in a matrix style, on columns. So for example, if I had an array input:

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15`

Then the matrix would be (for numRows = 3, numCols=5):

```
1 4 7 10 13
2 5 8 11 14
3 6 9 12 15
```

This means the real array would be:

```
1 4 7 10 13 2 5 8 11 14 3 6 9 12 15
```

How would I do that?

Here is my take:

````
int v[15] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
    int matrix[15];

    int row = 0, col = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
        matrix[col * 5 + row] = v[i];
        printf("row = %d col = %d\n", row, col);
        row++;
        
        if (row == 3) {
            row = 0;
            col++;
        }
        
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Can you just use [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)?

Comment: @scg how would I use the formula?

Comment: What I'm saying is that you could just store your matrices in column-major order to begin with. Then you wouldn't have to convert. As for your code though, you're moving in the right direction, but the math isn't right yet. Check the statement `matrix[col * 5 + row] = v[i]`. This indexes outside the bounds of the array. For example, for column 4 and row 2, the index is 22, which is invalid.

Comment: Okay so what should it be, then? What would be the formula?

Comment: I try to be careful about answering homework questions outright, so is this homework? (I'll still answer - I just want to be careful about just giving the answer in that case.)

Comment: @scg It's a personal project, this is something I have stumbled upon yesterday and trying to figure out

Answer (score 0):

You were very close in your last code example. The short answer is that rather than this:

```c++
matrix[col * 5 + row] = v[i];
```

You want:

```c++
matrix[row * 5 + col] = v[i];
```

In other words, 'row' and 'col' need to be the other way around.

Here's your example with that change made, and the results printed at the end:

```c++
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int v[15] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
    int matrix[15];

    int row = 0, col = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
        matrix[row * 5 + col] = v[i];
        printf("row = %d col = %d\n", row, col);
        row++;
        
        if (row == 3) {
            row = 0;
            col++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", matrix[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The output at the end for me is:

```
1 4 7 10 13 2 5 8 11 14 3 6 9 12 15
```

Which appears to match the output you were after in your post.

There are multiple conversions that can be made here: from 2-d row/column indices to 1-d indices in row- or column-major order, and from 1-d indices in row- or column-major order to 2-d row/column indices. The math is fairly simple for all the conversions (converting from 1-d to 2-d indices involves integer division and modulus). Once you figure out the conversions you need, I suggest creating a little library of functions for performing the conversions so that you have the functionality available when you need it.

Lastly, a couple general suggestions. Your original code wrote outside array bounds, which wasn't checked for, at least in what you posted. For exploratory work like this, I'd suggest using bounds checking so that you can detect errors more easily. (For example, in this case you could use `std::array` and the `at()` function.) This will help you catch a certain class of mistakes early.

I'd also suggest using named constants, even in a small example like this, e.g. 'numRows' and 'numCols' instead of 3 and 5, and 'numElements' as the product of those instead of 15. This will also help avoid errors, and will also make the code easier to read and understand (both for you and others).